# How to lazy load images in ionic slider?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have lots of device gallery local images path, which i am retrieving using [Ionic PhotoLibrary](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/photo-library/). Then i am trying to display those images using ionic slider as below :

```
<ion-slides>
     <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of images">
          <img [src]="img.photoURL | cdvPhotoLibrary"/>
     </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Where,
***images*** is the array of the LibraryItem. Then ***photoURL*** contains the `cdvfilepath://` of the images.

But, the slider working proper only if there are 2 to 3 images. When number of images increase app will crash.

Please give me solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-lazyload-image library.

install it via `npm install ng-lazyload-image --save`

and then declare it in app.module.ts as

```
import { LazyLoadImageModule, intersectionObserverPreset } from 'ng-lazyload-image';
```

and add it in imports

```
LazyLoadImageModule.forRoot({
    preset: intersectionObserverPreset
  })
```

Then just add `[lazyLoad]="image"` in place of `src="image"`
where you want to lazyload image.

Tested it myself and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did as you say, but it not work for me. After adding this i am not able to load page even. Definitely your answer may work if i use uri for my image path, but i am using cdvphotolibrary:// path to display image so it is not working for me. It may work whan <img> tag will use simple uri path for image.